# How to set a "base URL" for Webrat, Mechanize

Tags: ruby, cucumber, mechanize, webrat, mechanize-ruby

I would like to specify a base URL so I don't have to always specify absolute URLs. How can I specify a base URL for Mechanize to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish the previously proffered answer using Webrat, you can do the following e.g. in your Cucumber env.rb:

```
require 'webrat'

Webrat.configure do |config|
  config.mode = :mechanize
end

World do
  session = Webrat::Session.new
  session.extend(Webrat::Methods)
  session.extend(Webrat::Matchers)
  session.visit 'http://yoursite/yourbasepath/'
  session
end
```

To make it more robust, such as for use in different environments, you could do:

```
ENV['CUCUMBER_HOST'] ||= 'yoursite'
ENV['CUCUMBER_BASE_PATH'] ||= '/yourbasepath/'

# Webrat
require 'webrat'

Webrat.configure do |config|
  config.mode = :mechanize
end

World do
  session = Webrat::Session.new
  session.extend(Webrat::Methods)
  session.extend(Webrat::Matchers)
  session.visit('http://' + ENV['CUCUMBER_HOST'] + ENV['CUCUMBER_BASE_PATH'])
  session
end
```

Note that if you're using Mechanize, Webrat will also fail to follow your redirects because it won't interpret the current host correctly. To work around this, you can add `session.header('Host', ENV['CUCUMBER_HOST'])` to the above.

To make sure the right paths are being used everywhere for visiting and matching, add `ENV['CUCUMBER_BASE_PATH'] +` to the beginning of your paths_to method in paths.rb, if you use it. It should look like this:

```
  def path_to(page_name)
    ENV['CUCUMBER_BASE_PATH'] + 

    case page_name
```

Apologies if anyone got a few e-mails from this -- I originally tried to post as a comment and Stack Overflow's irritating UI got the better of me.

Answer (score 1):

For Mechanize, the first URL you specify will be considered the base URL. For example:

```
require "rubygems"
require "mechanize"

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get("http://some-site.org")

# Subsequent requests can now use the relative path:

agent.get("/contact.html")
```

This way you only specify the base URL once.